# Filtering out a value LIST[i] while looping through a LIST

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list:

```
lst = [3, 2, 1]
```

I will loop through the list, but I want to exclude lst[i] for each iteration. I seen answers like:

```
x = [i for i in range(n) if i not in y]
```

Which creates a range of numbers and then exclude a certain value, but that doesn't work for my code since I have a list that I want to loop through and a number lst[i] that I want to exclude. I couldn't fit it into my code specifically.

My pseduo code is as follows:

```
lst = [3,2,1]
new_lst = []

for i in range(0, len(lst)):

  new_list.append(i) while not including lst[i]

  Multiply everything in the new list (without List[i])
  result = np.prod(new_list)

  print(result)
```

Please help

Comment: That should be too slow anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Use a slice that excludes `i`: `lst[:i] + lst[i+1:]`

Comment: can you be more specific? How do I do this?

Comment: @agnostic you'll need to [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61065520/edit) to add some example input and output

Comment: Problem is I can't get the code to work to produce an example, my pseudo code give a pretty clear picture of what I'm trying to do through, does it not?

Comment: @agnostic oh sorry I mean *desired* output - the output you want to get. The pseudocode is not clear, that's why I ask.

Comment: I have updated my pseudo code.....does it make more sense now?

Comment: At least to me it does not. Can you please give the output that you want to get? Like: "I have the lst = [3, 2, 1]. I want the result [9, 4, 1]."

Comment: @agnostic Honestly I don't care about the pseudocode, just want to see the desired output. But FWIW it's mostly the `while not including lst[i]` that confuses me.

Comment: well basically in a list A = [3,2,1], I want to loop through A but not include A[i]. So basically as I loop through A, I will have a new list B = [2,1] when i =0, B = [3,1] when i =1 and B = [3,2] when i = 2. In the end I wanted to multiply everything in the list B during each iteration and print it out. So I will have B = 2, B= 3 and B = 6. Does that make sense?

Comment: @agnostic So you want `B = lst[:i] + lst[i+1:]`?

Comment: Yes. but I'm not sure how to write that out in python3

Answer (score 1):

You are essentially asking for combinations of size `len(lst) - 1`:

```
from itertools import combinations

lst = [3, 2, 1]
print(list(combinations(lst, len(lst) - 1)))
```

which outputs

```
[(3, 2), (3, 1), (2, 1)]
```